# Configure doesn't read --with-openssl-dir during static Tor compilation

Tags: c, compilation, openssl, tor

I'm trying to compile a static version of Tor with MinGW-w64 (MSYS 2). I've downloaded the Tor source (tor-0.3.1.8) and according to the INSTALL and COMPILE file I've compiled static version of OpenSSL (openssl-1.1.0g), zLib (zlib-1.2.11) and Libevent (libevent-2.1.8-stable)

To compile OpenSSL I've used

```
perl Configure mingw no-shared no-dso --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl
make depend
make
make install
```

The compilation success and I can find the libssl.a and libcrypto.a in /usr/local/openssl/lib/. I've used no-share and no-dso as INSTALL file in tor source dir declares.

To compile zLib I've used

```
make -fwin32/Makefile.gcc
```

To compile Libevent I've used

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libevent --disable-shared --enable-static --with-pic
make
make install
```

The compilation is ok and I can find all files in /usr/local/libevent. I've used --disable-shared --enable-static --with-pic as written in INSTALL file inside tor source code.

After I've launched the configure script for Tor

```
 ./configure --enable-static-tor --with-libevent-dir=/usr/local/libevent --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl --with-zlib-dir=/home/Nicola/tor-mingw/zlib-1.2.11
```

as written in INSTALL file.
The configuration script end with error after it has checked Libevent with success

```
checking for openssl directory... (system)
checking whether we need extra options to link openssl... (none)
configure: error: "You must specify an explicit --with-openssl-dir=x option when using --enable-static-openssl"
```

I've tried adding / after each dir, but nothing changes. Is it a script error that can be solved setting manually TOR_OPENSSL_LIBS with ?

```
TOR_OPENSSL_LIBS="/usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a"
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--enable-static-openssl` to your Tor configure command to tell it to link against a static OpenSSL library.  You'll need the same for libevent and zlib.

For reference, here's what I use to build Tor (it's not completely static like you are going for):

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/tor-$VERSION --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var \
--enable-static-openssl --with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl \
--enable-lzma --enable-zstd \
--with-tor-user=tor --with-tor-group=tor
```

On a side note, if you can build OpenSSL with the `enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128` flag, then ECDH will be much faster.

I use this to build static OpenSSL library for Tor:

```
./config no-shared zlib-dynamic \
--prefix=/opt/openssl --openssldir=/opt/openssl \
-fPIC enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128
```

Hope that helps.